# JSP variables concatenated as string at output by checking the null fields

Tags: html, jsp, el

I want to print the address in the following order and I was able to do that. My problem is for some users some address fields are null then it is printing like this (1804 E Broadway, , 223344) and also I want divide the address in to lines.

```
<td>${addr1 }, ${addr2 }, ${postalCode }</td>
```

Comment: Can you make an example? What would you like the output to be if some of the fields are null?

Comment: You used several tags together on the question that are confusing in that combination. What language are you using to generate your output? Is it .jsp server side, or JavaScript (which could be either client or browser side and could be using a package like handlebars)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirement is 3 ways:

**1. JSP EL**

```
 <!-- here I am using adjacent EL expression because string concat will not work here and if we put EL expression in new line one space is adding-->
 <td>${addr1 }${empty addr1? '': ','} 
 ${addr2 }${empty addr2? '': ','} 
 ${postalCode }</td>
```

**2. JSTL**

```
<c:if test="${not empty addr1}">
   ${addr1},
</c:if>
```

**3. Using java code in JSP**

I will not recommend this method because writing java code in JSP is not encouraged.

```
<%= (addr1 != null && addr1 !="") ? addr1 +",": "" %>
```

Comment: hi this looks pretty clear explanation thanks for your response I was going with JSP EL Its working good for me

Comment: @yaswanthAVULA can you accept my answer as it is working for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator in your JSP like this:

```
<%= (field != null && field !="") ? field +",": "" %>
```